# How to set BluetoothLEAdvertisementType for BLE GATT Server

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to implement BLE GATT Server on Windows 10 that could be connected with client. The only UWP reference I could find is BluetoothAdvertisement sample that seems to be implicitly implementing NonConnectableUndirected type.

How can I configure this server implementation to a different advertisement type (didn't find any reference on that)?

I'm running Windows 10 Insider Preview 15063 build with latest UWP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

GATT Server is a feature newly added in Windows 10 Creators Update. There is no official sample for GATT Server now. We’re a little light on the documentation right now, but we will remedy that soon.

For more info, please see [New Bluetooth features in Windows 10 Creators Update](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/13/new-bluetooth-features-in-creators-update-gatt-server-bluetooth-le) and also [**Bluetooth GATT Server**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server).

And for the [Bluetooth advertisement sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement) you've mentioned, it just shows how to use the [Bluetooth Advertisement API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.aspx) to send and receive Bluetooth Low Energy advertisements. This sample is not related to GATT Server.

> The Bluetooth Advertisement API provides an app with a simple but powerful set of methods that allow the following:
>
> - Receive advertisement data from Bluetooth LE peripherals with configurable filtering capabilities.
> - Send out Bluetooth LE advertisements allowing the app to operate as a source of beacon advertisements.

So it can only sends beacon advertisements, that's why the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementType` is `NonConnectableUndirected`. [NonConnectableUndirected](http://NonConnectableUndirected) corresponds with the `ADV_NONCONN_IND` type defined in the Bluetooth LE specifications. And `ADV_NONCONN_IND` is the advertisement type used when the peripheral does not want to accept connections, which is typical in Beacons.

Comment: The API described in **Bluetooth GATT Server**  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server) seems to be not implemented yet. For example, `GattUuid` is not found and fails compilation.

Comment: @user2156173 see stackoverflow.com/questions/43385167/can´t-find-new-bluetooth-le-gatt-apis-for-uwp

Comment: @user2156173 The docs need to be updated, as that class was removed. [GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattserviceprovider#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_GenericAttributeProfile_GattServiceProvider_CreateAsync_) simply takes a GUID now, and there is a [BluetoothUuidHelper.FromShortId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothuuidhelper#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_BluetoothUuidHelper_FromShortId_) to convert a short ID to a 128-bit UUID.

Comment: @user2156173 [The document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server) has update, you can have a check.